# Creating a hashmap of array list not working as expected

Tags: java, list

I'm pretty new to Java so sorry if this is super basic.  Basically I have some data in a array list and it works fine but in a later part of my program I need to read the list and it takes a long time because the list becomes very large.  So I thought I could take certain parts of the array list(thats needed later) into a hash map that I can extract that section of the array list later from(hopefully that makes sense).

I first create the array list with all the data I want(I have a loop and call each data thats created in a single loop data_cache_local_loop):

```
HashMap hashmap_of_values = new HashMap(); //hashmap of arraylist
for (int i = 0; i<100; i++) {
....program logic and more loops
Set uniqie_T_cache = new HashSet(T_cache_local_loop); //make values unique
hashmap_of_values.put(i, new ArrayList(uniqie_T_cache));
}
```

Then later on when I need the data I extract it like this:

```
List t = new ArrayList();
t.add(hashmap_of_values.get(i));
```

But my program fails and I'm not sure exactly why.  When I print out the size of hashmap_of_values I get the number of i's I'm expecting but when I print out the number of T it only shows one(when I run the program it says T_cache_local_loop has hundreds of items).

Can anyone suggest to me what I'm doing wrong?  I'm not 100% but I think I maybe looking at the array list I add as a single item but I'm unsure of what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Honestly, one thing I've never understood is that I have the right to edit but I alone can not review/accept an edit. Doesn't make too much sense IMO, I should just do it myself... But then since an edit is pending, I _can't_ do it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should really be using generics -- it'd help you a lot, and make these issues much more obvious -- but for the moment your problem is that that line should be

```
List t = (List) hashmap_of_values.get(i);
```

or

```
List t = new ArrayList((List) hashmap_of_values.get(i));
```

to get a copy of the list in the map.  What you *were* doing was creating a list of lists, because `hashmap_of_values.get(i)` was already a list.

Comment: Because basically the code from the OP is creating a list of lists of values instead of a list of values. (in case that wasn't clear).

Comment: ahh your right. I thought I was doing that but wasn't sure how to stop it.  Didn't realize I could simply cast the list when creating the t variable.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

trying `t.addAll(hashmap_of_values.get(i));`

Answer (score 0):

When you add your `HashSet` to your `ArrayList`, you're adding the entire set as a single object to the first index of the `ArrayList`. You're **not** adding each element of the `HashSet` to the `ArrayList`. Instead, you should do something like:

```
List newList= new ArrayList();
newList.addAll( unique_T_cache );
hashmap_of_values.put(i, unique_T_cache );
```